# Laravel 8 UniSharp File Manager 3 change base directory from app/storage to app/public

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-manager

I am struggling to change the base directory to upload images to be in `app/public` instead of the *default* `app/storage`.

There is no `base_directory` in the **config/lfm.php** file.

I also see that the **lfm.php** file is in the **unisharp/laravel-filemanager/src/config** folder. Why is this config file in 2 places?

The reason I need to change to have this structure is that I already have hundreds of images in `public/images` and files in `public/files` and I want to keep these links in the existing pages working.

So what do I have to do to change that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you change in `config/lfm.php`, line with `'disk' => 'lfm_local'`, resolve your problem.

`lfm_local` is localized in the `file config/filesystems.php`, there you see some options of disks, to use at `lfm.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed config it in `config/lfm.php` at line `'disk' => 'lfm_local'` did work. No idea why the author didn't mark above answer as correct asnswer.

My practice is registering a `FILE_SYSTEM_DISK` variable in .env file if it's was not there yet.
Using this env variable to set disk type at `disk` in `config/lfm.php` and
`default` in `config/filesystems.php` got my file system synced well with LM.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35201537)